# need to select to choose the selected option in doing a reset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a reset and its working well for all fields except select

```
$("form").find("input[type=text] , textarea , select").each(function(){
          $(this).val('');

        });
```

not sure even in console inspect element, it shows selected but the actual element shows an empty select

Answer (score 0):

In order to reset the select input, you can set the `selectedIndex` as follows:

```
$('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `$("form").reset()`?

That will use the default reset that comes with the browser

You can even do `<input type="reset" value="Reset" />`